# How to Specify XML Encoding when Serializing an Object in C#

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8

I am serializing a C# object into an XML document and sending the XML document to a third party vendor.  The vendor is telling me that the encoding specification in the document is UTF-16, but the XML document contains UTF-8 content and they can't use it.  Here is the code I am using to create the XML file, which runs without error and creates an XML document.

```
// Instantiate xmlSerializer with my object type.
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));

// Instantiate a new stream and pass file location and mode.
Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\doc.xml", FileMode.Create);

// Instantiate xmlWriter and pass stream and encoding.
XmlWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode);

// Call serialize method and pass xmlWriter and my object.
xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, myObject);

// Close writer and stream.
xmlWriter.Close();
stream.Close();
```

When I run this, the XML Doc shows this on the first line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

I've tried changing the Encoding from Encoding.Unicode to Encoding.UTF8 in the XmlTextWriter, but that doesn't change the first line of the XML Doc and it still shows UTF-16.

I also tried using the Serialize method signature that takes 4 parameters (writer, object, namespaces, encoding) and specified UTF8 as the encoding and that didn't change the XML Doc specification either.

I believe all I need to do is change the encoding that shows in the XML Doc to UTF-8 and the third party vendor will be happy. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I change from `Encoding.Unicode` to `Encoding.UTF8`, the file is generated properly. Perhaps you're looking at an old version of your file?

In an unrelated bit, you should use `using` for deterministic disposal of objects which implement `IDisposable`:

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));

using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@".\doc.xml", FileMode.Create))
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, myObject);
}
```

Comment: I'll try again and double check.

Comment: I ran the code again after changing the encoding to UTF8 and it still outputs an XML doc with UTF-16 specification.  I'll change the code to use the using instead of the close.

Comment: Well, I'm an idiot.  There were two places (events) where I was doing this and I was changing it in one place and testing it from the other event.  It works.  Changing the encoding in the XmlWriter to UTF8 works.